# Could not load file or assembly 'WindowsBase, Version 4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Got a fresh machine this morning and went and installed Visual Studio 2012 and this is the error I get when it starts up

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Could not load file or assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

After it shows this message Visual Studio Closes out. I have tried reinstalling from a ISO first time I did a web install. Google isn't very helpful

Comment: WHat is your framwork target ? 4.5 ?

Comment: well this is starting Visual Studio so target doesn't matter at this point

Comment: It found the file, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll, but the content of the file is corrupted.  Better send that "fresh" machine back, never a good sign when things go bad this early.

Comment: I did a repair and it fixed everything ... I was afraid I would have to send it back :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of repair/uninstall/reinstall, I did install windows update, because my system was crash during installing updates. After this crash I faced the same issue but now it resolve.
:-)

Answer (score 1):

I did a **repair** instead of a uninstall / reinstall  and this solved my issue.