# Unable to open Visual Studio 2015, it throw an error "ProcessDPIAwareness"

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm unable to open Visual Studio 2015, it thrown me an error 
"***could not load type 'ProcessDPIAwareness' from assembly 'WindowsBase, version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKey Token=31bf3856ad364e35'***".

I'm using visual studio 2015 professional edition and .Net framework 4.6.1, Attached screenshot for your reference.

[image: Visual Studio invoke Error]

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506938/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-windowsbase-version-4-0-0-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I cannot open visual studio 2017 ProcessDPIawareness error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362577/i-cannot-open-visual-studio-2017-processdpiawareness-error)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys, I tried lot of options like Repair, uninstall & reinstall a fresh copy, but none of these options worked for me. As Piyin said "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14506938/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-windowsbase-version-4-0-0-0" I will try with windows updates and let you know the result.

Comment: Windows update doesn't help on this, plan to format the machine. If you guys have any other suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can able to access visual studio only after formatting machine & install new visual studio setup.